# Does using .jpg instead of .png reduces iOS app size if alpha component is not requirement?

Tags: ios, xcode

.PNG carries extra information of Alpha (I may not be 100% correct). However, if image asset requirement without alpha channel, can we opt for .jpg (which is lesser size compared to .PNG) for images asset use for the iOS app?. Does it help reducing overall .ipa size?

Other posts are specifying more on .png crush or app thinning. However I wanted to know if there are known issues we may encounter because of changing the .png to .jpg for the image assets.

Comment: No issues if you don't want transparent images.

Comment: This all depends on the image. If an image has a lot of solid color areas, png version will be a lot smaller than the jpg counterpart.

Comment: @Desdenova yep agreed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PNG's require very little extra CPU energy to display.L arge PNGs may take longer to read from storage than more compressed image formats, and thus be slower to display.

JPG's are smaller to store but to display them requires a much more complicated decoding algorithm. The typical compression and image quality is usually quite sufficient for photos.

Use JPG's for photos and for anything large, and PNG's for anything small like icons or as a part of a composited transparent overlay

So if you are showing a lot of images not icons use JPG that will affect app size.

Other then that read about 'App thinning' check Apple's Video https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/404/